# CardView in fragment is invisible

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I have a main activity (ActivityMain.java) that I would like to use to navigate between four fragments. In one of these fragments, I'm attempting to place a CardView in conjunction with a RecyclerView to create a vertical list of cards. However, so far I've been unable to get any of the cards to display when I run the app. The CardView will display perfectly in Android Studio's design preview, but when an actual device/emulator is used it disappears.

I've tried to manually set the visibility of the CardView through Java, but it continued to stay invisible. I believe that the fragment's layout could be covering the CardView's layout, but I'm still very new to Android development so I'm not completely sure what the problem could be.

Below I've pasted the classes and XML files that are likely to be associated with my problem.

**AdapterMainFeed.java**

```
public class AdapterMainFeed extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterMainFeed.ViewHolderMainFeed> {
    private ArrayList<Article> listArticlesMain = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AdapterMainFeed(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setArticlesMain(ArrayList<Article> listArticlesMain) {
        this.listArticlesMain = listArticlesMain;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderMainFeed onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup container, int i) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_main_feed, container, false);
        Article article1 = new Article("asdf", "ghj", "klm", new Date(0));
        Article article2 = new Article("sdfg", "hjk", "lmn", new Date(0));
        Article article3 = new Article("dfgh", "jkl", "mno", new Date(0));
        listArticlesMain.add(article1);
        listArticlesMain.add(article2);
        listArticlesMain.add(article3);
        return new ViewHolderMainFeed(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderMainFeed viewHolderMainFeed, int i) {
        Article currentArticle = listArticlesMain.get(i);
        viewHolderMainFeed.articleTitle.setText(currentArticle.getTitle());
        viewHolderMainFeed.articleAuthor.setText(currentArticle.getAuthor());
        viewHolderMainFeed.articleWebsite.setText(currentArticle.getWebsite());
        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        final String timePosted = formatter.format(currentArticle.getTimePosted());
        viewHolderMainFeed.articleTime.setText(timePosted);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listArticlesMain.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolderMainFeed extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView articleTitle;
        TextView articleAuthor;
        TextView articleWebsite;
        TextView articleTime;

        public ViewHolderMainFeed(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            articleTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainArticleTitle);
            articleAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainArticleAuthor);
            articleWebsite = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainArticleWebsite);
            articleTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainArticleTime);
        }
    }  
}
```

**view_main_feed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context="com.convergeapp.converge.ActivityMain">

   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPurpleSeance"
        android:id="@+id/mainArticleCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainArticleLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainArticleTitle"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainArticleAuthor"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/mainArticleTitle"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainArticleWebsite"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mainArticleTime"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainArticleTime"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have posted an excess amount of code... See how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DizzyCode My apologies. I've cut out the code that wasn't directly related to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around with some changes, I finally discovered the solution. What I did was add the Article objects to the list in the main fragment's onCreateView method. Additionally, I instantiated CardView in the ViewHolder, though that didn't help me see the cards initially.

So, if you're ever in a similar predicament and can't figure out the solution, try to actually create the objects before setting them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call notifyDataSetChanged(); inside onCreateViewHolder after adding the new articles so that the itemcount is updated

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider that. However, the cards that are supposed to be displaying the data still aren't visible.